# Google-style “Your network is generating too much traffic” bounce for postfix

Tags: postfix, spam, rate-limiting

I'm being attacked from a botnet and I found out about it because I got this email from mailer-daemon telling me there's no space left on device. The mail.log was filled up with messages like

```
Dec 5 01:56:14 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx postfix/smtpd[9634]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dynamic.hinet.net[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx>: Relay access denied; from=<xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx> to=<xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx> proto=SMTP helo=<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
```

I wrote a botnet killer script. The script uses iptables to ban NETWORK RANGES with too many IP ADDRESSES trying to send messages through my server, producing the above messages in logfile.

I'm sure this can kill a legitimate traffic. I decided I need this traffic to be as follows:

```
S0 - standard traffic - <1 mail per minute
S1 - increased traffic - 1+ mail per minute
S2 - suspicious traffic - 10+ mails per minute
S3 - potentially unwanted traffic - 1+ mails per second
S4 - attack - 5+ mails per second
```

...treated as follows:

```
S0: No action
S1: Log
S2: Log&MailReport (to postmaster@localhost)
S3: Log&MailReport&AutoBounce (solve capcha at http://myhost.tld/anti-spam )
S4: Log&MailReport&AutoBounce (you were temporarily blocked by the mailserver)
S5: Log&MailReport&AutoBounce&AutoAbuseReport (User x@y.z is abusing our server)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using postfix? If not - is there any better mailserver for that?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:** I've completely rewritten this question because people got confused and thought it was an open relay

Comment: No server is ever required to be an open relay. If you think this is required, you're doing it wrong and need to do it differently.

Comment: Open relay is never a good idea. Only use an open relay in a private network for testing purpose.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason for needing to be an open relay? It sounds like an awful lot of administrative headache for something that is universally frowned upon.

Comment: Why not just [use RBLs](http://www.howtoforge.com/block_spam_at_mta_level_postfix)?

Comment: It shouldn't have been an open relay on the internet for any length of time.  You are contributing to the spam problem.  Configure you server properly and your problem goes away.  Only allow relay from known IPs and/or require authentication.  Only accept delivery to the domain(s) in question.

Comment: @NathanC I use RBLs. This is still producing a high amount of liles filling up my logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality, it's just the nature of running an Internet-facing mail server. I run one on-premise as our corporate mail and we get slammed with spam mails every few seconds. The only thing you can really do is implement `logrotate` and prevent the logs from growing out of control. If you need them for historical reasons, `gzip` can compress them as much as 90% or more.

If you'd like to take a look at this, check out [this](https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/utilities/logrotate) article that has tons of how-to information.

Comment: Thank you. This and fail2ban solves the problem pretty neatly.